# How does malloc know which type the returned pointer is pointing at?

Tags: c, memory, cs50

I'm learning pointers and memory allocation with C. I've used the snippet below to manually allocate some bunch of bytes to copy:

```
char *s = get_string("s: "); // this is included in cs50 library and it returns a char pointer
char *t = malloc(strlen(s) + 1); // +1 for "\0"
...
free(t);
```

My question is this, why do we declare `t` as it points to a char value? How does `malloc` know that the pointer `t` points at a `char` value, even if we did not enter any "clue" about using `char`?

Comment: `malloc()` does not know what you intend to do with the pointer it returns, hence it is of type `void*`, which can be assigned to another pointer type. All it knows is the number of bytes you need.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So, the `malloc` function returns a `void*` pointer, and are we casting that to `char` when we declare `t` as `char *t`?

Comment: Your code is not (and in C should not) casting the pointer, it is a simple assignment to `char *t`. You, the programmer, chose this type because you want it to point to a "string", an array of `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't, and it doesn't need to. `malloc` allocates a block of exactly as many bytes as you tell it to, and returns a `void*` pointer to it. The pointer is then implicitly converted to `char*` when the assignment is made. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc#:%7E:text=In%20C%2C%20you%20don%27t,compiler%2C%20a%20cast%20is%20needed.) for more insight.